# How to post on Facebook wall without opening Dialog?

Tags: iphone, fbconnect

I am trying to integrate facebook in my app. I had done code for login and trying to post on my wall but I don't need the facebook dialog. I want my own. after googling I found some code but its not working. It is not giving any error but not posting any thing...

Here I am using is :

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"Facebook developer Test Message",@"message",
                               @"Test it!",@"name",                                   
                               nil];
 Facebook *fb = [[Facebook alloc] init];
    [fb requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed"   // or use page ID instead of 'me'
                      andParams:params
                  andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                    andDelegate:self];
```

Its not working..

```
 FBStreamDialog *dialog = [[[FBStreamDialog alloc] init]
     autorelease];
 dialog.userMessagePrompt = @"Enter your message:";
 dialog.attachment = [NSString
   stringWithFormat:@"{\"name\":\"Facebook Connect for iPhone\",\"href\":\"http://developers.facebook.com/connect.phptab=iphone\",\"caption\":\"Caption\", \"description\":\"Description\",\"media\":[{\"type\":\"image\",\"src\":\"http://img40.yfrog.com/img40/5914/iphoneconnectbtn.jpg\",\"href\":\"http://developers.facebook.com/connect.php?tab=iphone/\"}],\"properties\":{\"another link\":{\"text\":\"Facebook home page\",\"href\":\"http://www.facebook.com\"}}}"];

 [dialog show];
```

This opens a dialog and ask me to type message and when I clicks It post the Data on my wall.

I Had refferes following links for this

http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=79466

Please tell me where I am doing mistake.

Thanks

Comment: Which of the delegate methods are called?

Comment: Also, you might want to accept a few answers.

Comment: You might also consider voting on a few answers as well.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion I respects for that..I want to do that but I didn't get any very good answer for my questions. But Sure I will keep voting from now.. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

hi i think you can do this and can solve your problem

```
NSString *str=@"Your String to post";

NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   str,@"message",
                                   @"Test it!",@"name",                                   
                                   nil];
Facebook *fb = [[Facebook alloc] init];
    [fb requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed"   // or use page ID instead of 'me'
                          andParams:params
                      andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                        andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: Isn't that _exactly_ the same as Kapil's original (except you've declared an extra, unnecessary variable).

Comment: yes but this will work with Graphics API so i think it will also work in your application.

Comment: Hey Folk, this is right and I was right too. my mistake was I hadn't understood fbgraph API well